# Use Maclaurin series to get first 4 terms of power series

Tags: power-series

By modifying the Maclaurin series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$, how can I obtain the Maclaurin series for $\frac{-2}{1+4x^3}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know
$$\frac{1}{1-t} = 1 + t + t^2 + \cdots$$

Just take $t = -4x^3.$ Then

$$\frac{1}{1+4x^3} = \frac{1}{1-(-4x^3)} = 1 + (-4x^3) + (-4x^3)^2 + \cdots = 1 - 4x^3 + 16x^6 -\cdots.$$

Multiplying by $-2$ gets your series.

Comment: Thanks! Would this mean that 1 is the first term, (-4x^3) is the second term and so on?

Comment: That's a little bit ambiguous because it's not clear whether the zero terms in the power series are included, so it's not clear whether they want the first four nonzero terms or if they want a Maclaurin polynomial of order $3.$ That said I would assume they mean the first, so yes that would be correct. (but remember to include the extra factor of $-2$)

Comment: So -2, (-2)(-4x^3), (-2)(-4x^3)^2, (-2)(-4x^3)^3?